# What should I install for node to image consisting of values (png) to text to be printed in the console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, protractor

I am using nodejs, protractor, selenium webdriver for taking screen shot of
 a graph(successful), but now I have to convert the image(png) which consists of values when mouse hover a region.Now i want that number(eg 1.33) 
 from graph to be printed in the console for my future task. I tried OCRABYTE 
 nodemodule which was only able to print the values away from graph.Can anyone 
 help me which node module should i work or can i try with python.I used 
 tesseract but not able to get,so I want help in this.

Comment: are you trying to test the library that generates the graph to verify that it is showing this information correctly, or are you testing something else that this is the way that you are collecting the numbers?  If you are not actually testing the generation of the graph, then I recommend that you investigate other ways to obtain the data that's used in the graph.  It will be MUCH simpler.  E.g. you may find that making a simple js request on the page will spit out JSON with the data used in the graph.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.